# how can i add button Titlebar in android PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Tags: android, button, titlebar

I want to add a button in titlebar .I googled but all code is with xml.I want to do programmatically.Can anybody get some reference ?

Can anybody help me?

THX.

Comment: why must you do it PROGRAMMATICALLY?!

Comment: I will do some dinamic actions.so i dont want with xml and i want to learn this way.

Comment: What do you think the "titlebar" is? Do you mean the action bar on Android 3.0+ devices? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I am thinking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538546/custom-title-bar-with-progress-in-android someone is pin with  yellow. I want to add buton here.

Comment: the link which u posted  is not a custom title bar, they have used theme NoTitleBar, and added a `tableRow/LinearLayout` at the top...even u can achieve something like that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find this useful. The post talks about using the application window to set a custom title bar. This title bar is an xml layout.

[Custom TitleBar Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time)